# how to "rewrite rule" for a sub-sub-directory? .htaccess/php

Tags: php, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have one folder named test located at www.mydomain.com/abc/files/test. I need to change the URLs from `www.mydomain.com/abc/files/test/test.php?id=15&key=some-text123`

to `www.mydomain.com/abc/files/test/15/some-text123` this is similiar to SO urls.

I tried following in .htaccess file with following code

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ test/test.php?id=$1&key=$2 [R]
```

It redirects me to `www.mydomain.com/test/test.php?id=15&key=some-text-123`
but it didnt work as I copied the format from somewhere. I am not sure ^ should include www part as well or it just assumes / as root?

The "id" part is important to me. I'll also consider followings as valid urls.

```
www.mydomain.com/abc/files/test/15 (without /some-text123")
www.mydomain.com/abc/files/test/15/ (without /some-text123 but having / )
```

Can you please help me write correct rule?

How can I make it so that I dont have to hard-code "abc/files/" ?

It shouldn't affect any of the other urls of my site(than "test" folder.)

Also the URL should stay the same (`/files/test/15 etc`) instead of changing to `"?id=15&key=some-text123"`

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`R` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) forces an external redirect. So just leave it away and the request will be redirected internally:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ test/test.php?id=$1&key=$2
```

Comment: i tried already .. doesnt work .. throws up "object not found"