# .htacces Nice urls for subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have 1 subfolder located at my root folder:
/root/task6/index.php

And I need to change urls `www.andriussulcas.prinusprojects.lt/task6/index.php?p=naujienos&title=title` to `www.andriussulcas.prinusprojects.lt/task6/naujienos/title`

I've been trying to do this for some time now and all my efforts weren't successful. 
While searching for answer, I started thinking that maybe my mod_rewrite wasn't activated. But later on I found how to redirect my web site root to subdirectory, where all my files are. So mod_rewrite works.

I found some similar answers here, on stackoverflow, like [how to "rewrite rule" for a sub-sub-directory? .htaccess/php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018383/how-to-rewrite-rule-for-a-sub-sub-directory-htaccess-php) but for some reason it doens't work for me.

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?andriussulcas.akademija.prinusprojects.lt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/task6/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /task6/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?andriussulcas.akademija.prinusprojects.lt$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ task6/index.php?p=naujienos [L]

RewriteRule ^naujienos/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php?p=naujienos&title=$1 [L]
```

.htaccess file is located at my root directory, and there are no other .htaccess files at subdirectories.

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your last rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?andriussulcas.akademija.prinusprojects.lt$ 
RewriteRule ^naujienos/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /task6/index.php?p=naujienos&title=$1 [L]
```